# How to replace all occurrences between two specific characters with the associated char Code using reqex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I'd like to replace everything between two characters with another string. I came up with this function:

```
String.prototype.unformat = function() {
  var s='';
  for (var i=0; i<this.length;i++) s+=this[i]
  return s.replace(/\$[^$]*\$/g, '')
};
```

Using a string like `'This is a test $33$'` and unformat it with the function above, it will return 'This is a test '.

Ok-cool, but I'd like to replace all occurrences in ( $ **...** $ ) with the associated char code.

In the example `'This is a test $33$'`, I like to replace $33$ with the result of the javascript `String.fromCharCode()` function to get the string `'This is a test !'` as result.

How to edit the prototype function above to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's no need to mess with the prototype of `String`. Just use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression and a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback function that returns `fromCharCode()` with the matched code

```js
String.prototype.unformat = function() {
  return this.replace(/\$([^$]*)\$/g, function (string, charcode) {
    return String.fromCharCode(charcode);
  });
};

console.log(("char: $33$").unformat());
```

In order to avoid any future problems, I would also adapt the regex to only match digits: `/\$(\d+)\$/g`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a match group `()` and replace it with the `String.fromCharCode` result:

```
String.prototype.unformat = function() {
    return this.replace(/\$(.*?)\$/g, function(match, group) { // the match is the whole match (including the $s), group is the matched group (the thing between the $s)
        return String.fromCharCode(group);
    });
};
```

**Notes:**

1. No need to copy the string as replace doesn't mutate the original string (`this`).
2. The match group `(.*?)` is a non-greedy one (lazy one) that matches as few characters as possible.
3. It is better if you don't mess around natives' prototypes (such as String, Number, ...).

**Example:**

```js
String.prototype.unformat = function() {
    return this.replace(/\$(.*?)\$/g, function(match, group) {
        return String.fromCharCode(group);
    });
};

console.log('This is a test $33$'.unformat());
```

Comment: `/\$(.*?)\$/g` -> `/\$(\d+)\$/g`. Anything but numbers will break the function